# How to use c++ functions in c?

Tags: c++, c

C++ can use c functions by `extern "C"`,

can c use c++ functions somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the same way, if you declare a **C++** function as `extern "C"`, **C** will be able to link with it.

Answer (score 6):

Not really. You can write a "C-compatible" function in C++, that is to say outside of any class or namespace and whose prototype does not use classes or references. If declared `extern "C"` then you could call such a function from C. The function could then go on to make use of whatever C++ features were useful for it.

Comment: can the c++ function declared extern "C" use any other classes in its function body?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to functions in c++, there are two types that come to mind: plain-old stand alone functions and member functions that're part of a class. There is no way to use the second type directly in C since it has no notion of an 'object'. Remember member functions have an implicit 'this' as a hidden first parameter.

You can, however, use the first type of function in C if you decorate it with the extern "C" declaration as part of the function prototype. This is needed to tell the C++ compiler to not 'mangle' the function name when you compile your source.

Comment: what if the plain-old stand alone functions uses other classes in its function body,can it still be used directly in c?

Comment: @compile-fan that is possible but only if you compiled that function in C++ mode and then link into your C code afterwards as a library or object file. The key observation here is you have to keep C++ specific code isolated behind that boundary.

Comment: @compile-fan - the C++ code can be called from C but the function is in C++

Answer (score 0):

C can use C++ functions only as functions from an external library.

Better way is to compile your C code with help of C++ compiler. Look here, please: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t288284-calling-c-from-c.html